# Bootstrap control alignment - line breaks even with display: inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, line-breaks

I need the "check" icon next to the text input control. input control has to have "form-control" class. The Icon goes to next line if i put the html (code) in a separate line, it stays next to the input control as long as the  tag is starting at the same line as  tag.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label class="control-label">OK</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" style="display: inline;"><i
      class="fa fa-check" style="display: inline; position: absolute;"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1"></div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label class="control-label">Not OK</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" style="display: inline;">
      <i class="fa fa-check" style="display: inline; position: absolute;"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I must add that this icon will be added by an angular directive. which will be applied to different input controls (text, checkbox, select or even other custom directives using such controls). It is ok even if this icon appears on top of the control (overlaps it) as seen in the image
`[image: can display the icon overlapping the control]

Comment: here is the plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/Fkxi5JMiOyd9SIvQ9qOJ

Comment: since people are recommending using add-on, i must mention here that add-on is not desired.in real application, this icon will be add by an angularjs directive, which will be applied to different kind of controls, text, checkboxe, select etc. position of the icon will be on right, and may overlap the control in some cases (appear inside the text input or select area). i will use z-index for that

Answer (score 1):

**add icon in after input by using Bootstrap**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="fontawesome@4.4.0" data-semver="4.4.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">OK</label>
              <div class="input-group add-on">
                <input type="text" name="userok" id="userok" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                <a class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Add some text here..."> 
                  <i class='fa fa-check'></i>
                </a>
              </span>
              </div>
              </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">Not OK</label>
              <div class="input-group add-on">
                <input type="text" name="usernotok" id="usernotok" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                <a class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Add some text here..."> 
                  <i class='fa fa-check'></i>
                </a>
              </span>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @shital-marakana but input-group add-on is not desired. it has to appear the way it shows in my example "OK"

Answer (score 0):

Please try the sample below

Note : Please add fa icon url (http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css)

```css
.input-group.input-group-mod input.form-control {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group-mod .input-group-addon {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputGroup">Input Group</label>
                <div class="input-group input-group-mod">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Search" id="inputGroup"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add on is not desired it has to be standalone icon. its ok even if it displays on top of (overlapped) the text input control